# Scala: Boolean to Option

Tags: scala

I have a Boolean and would like to avoid this pattern:

```
if (myBool) 
  Option(someResult) 
else 
  None
```

What I'd like to do is

```
myBool.toOption(someResult)
```

Any suggestions with a code example would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Starting `Scala 2.13`, `Option` has a [`when`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/Option$.html#when[A](cond:Boolean)(a:=%3EA):Option[A]) builder for this exact purpose:

```
Option.when(condition)(result)
```

For instance:

```
Option.when(true)(3)
// Option[Int] = Some(3)
Option.when(false)(3)
// Option[Int] = None
```

Also note [`Option.unless`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/Option$.html#unless[A](cond:Boolean)(a:=%3EA):Option[A]) which promotes the opposite condition.

Answer (score 59):

Scalaz has a way to do it with [BooleanOps.option](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/781b86d4ce835edad41359558bf50b69232c04a7/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/syntax/std/BooleanOps.scala#L218).
That would allow you to write :

```
myBool.option(someResult)
```

If you don't want to add a Scalaz dependency, just add the following in your code :

```
implicit class RichBoolean(val b: Boolean) extends AnyVal {
  final def option[A](a: => A): Option[A] = if (b) Some(a) else None
}
```

Comment: Because in Scala the imports are often as difficult to discover as the solution: `import scalaz.syntax.std.boolean._`

Comment: Thanks @cfeduke - for my defense, I did give the link to the source code file which makes it easy to find the import.

Comment: I wanted to do this with Cats, but these type enrichments are _obviously_ in [Mouse](https://github.com/benhutchison/mouse)...

Answer (score 20):

Option().collect() is a good pattern for this kind of thing.

```
Option(myBool).collect { case true => someResult }
```

from the REPL:

```
scala> (Option(true).collect { case true => 3 }, Option(false).collect { case true => 3 })
res3: (Option[Int], Option[Int]) = (Some(3),None)
```

Comment: drawbacks of this sollution:
1)almost the same amount of code(comparing to `if(predicate) Some(result) else None`)but semantics is weird
2)a bit of runtime overhead:
a)null test (can be mitigated with `Some(predicate)...`)
b)2 excessive objects are cteated(instances of Some and Lifted)
c)excessive function calls

Answer (score 16):

None of the other answers answer the question as stated!  To get the exact semantics you specified use:

```
implicit class BoolToOption(val self: Boolean) extends AnyVal {
  def toOption[A](value: => A): Option[A] =
    if (self) Some(value) else None
}
```

You can then write

```
myBool.toOption(someResult)
```

eg:

```
scala> true.toOption("hi")
res5: Option[String] = Some(hi)

scala> false.toOption("hi")
res6: Option[String] = None
```

Comment: If you put this e.g. in `object BoolImplicits { ... }`, then do `import BoolImplicits._` to be able to apply `toOption` to booleans.

Answer (score 9):

If you don't mind `someResult` being evaluated no matter the value of `myBool` you can also use

```
Some(someResult).filter(myBool)
```

Comment: Some(someResult).filter(_ => myBool)

Answer (score 4):

```
scala> PartialFunction.condOpt(5) { case x if true => x }
res9: Option[Int] = Some(5)

scala> PartialFunction.condOpt(5) { case x if false => x }
res10: Option[Int] = None
```

Here, the guard holds the condition and the value passed to `condOpt` is the value returned if the guard evaluates to true.

Answer (score 4):

Another choice:

```
implicit class RichOptionCompanion(val self: Option.type) extends AnyVal {
  def when[A](cond: Boolean)(value: => A): Option[A] = if(cond) Some(value) else None
}
```

Usage:

```
Option.when(foo != "bar") { ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class RichBool[T](a: Boolean, res:=> T) {
   def toOption: Option[T] = if (a) Some(res) else None
}
implicit def boolToRichBool[T](tp: (Boolean, T)): RichBool[T] = new RichBool(tp._1, tp._2);
```

This would give you:

```
(true, 5).toOption // Some(5);
(false, 3).toOption // None
```

Comment: You may want to declare your argument as `(a:Boolean, res: =>T)` to avoid evaluating `res` in case a=false

Answer (score 2):

Here are a couple things I would consider:

```
val bool: Boolean = ???
val result = 1337    

Option(bool).withFilter(identity).map(_ => result)
```

or

```
for {
  opt <- Option(bool)
  if opt
} yield result
```

Comment: Hello, first of all, welcome to StackOverflow. Now... instead of just posting your code could you please elaborate on what it does, how and why ? It is customary on SO to give an explanation along with code/links to docs etc so that people who ask questions understand better. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
Option(true).find(_ == true) // Some(true)
Option(false).find(_ == true) // None
```