# Idiomatic way of If none return false?

Tags: scala

The java library I am dealing with, returns `null` on errors. Is there an Idiomatic way of saying:

```
val x:Option[T]

if(x.isEmpty)
 false
else
 x.get.isFooable()
```

I have looked at the answers at [Scala: Boolean to Option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19690531/scala-boolean-to-option). Those are close to what I want, there is more idiomatic way then:

```
x.isDefined && x.get.isFooable()
```

Comment: I think it's safe to say that calling `get` is generally not idiomatic and kind of defeats the purpose of `Option`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The are many ways to process Option. Most idiomatic is lift computation to Option:

```
val x = Option(true)
x map { if(_) 10 else 20 }
```

If you use Option[Boolean] for conditional branching than pattern matching is most preferable:

```
c match {
  case Some(true)  => println("True")
  case Some(false) => println("False")
  case None        => println("Undefined")
}
```

And your case:

```
x.isDefined && x.get.isFooable()
```

little bit clearly:

```
x map { _.isFooable } getOrElse false
```

and finally with Scala `Option` utility method:

```
x exists { _.isFooable }
```

Comment: or better yet `x.fold(false)(_.isFooable)`

Comment: I found [Tony Morris Option Cheat Sheet](http://blog.tmorris.net/scalaoption-cheat-sheet/)
 on it I found, `x.exists(_.isFooAble() )`.

Answer (score 10):

```
x.exists(_.isFooable) // Returns false if x is None
```

If you want `true` as the default for `None`, use `x.forall`

Answer (score 3):

```
x map (_.isFooable) getOrElse false
```

Answer (score 1):

You want

```
x map (_.isFooAble()).getOrElse(false)
```